Simplifying Sentences that Precede a Conditional
Suppose we have the following proposition:
Suppose that $x \in \mathbb Z$, that $a$ is even, and that $b$ is odd. If $x^2-ax+b$ is even, then $x$ is odd.
I am not interested in proving the proposition; I am more curious about the structure of it. Namely, suppose I present a second, similar proposition:
If $x \in \mathbb Z$, that $a$ is even, $b$ is odd, and $x^2-ax+b$ is even, then $x$ is odd.
Are these two propositions the same? If not, why? If they are the same, which is more "proper"? Is there a particular reason one would prefer one over the other? I know this is likely trivial, but I cannot seem to find answers about this issue elsewhere.

This is just currying.

They are logically equivalent, so what matters here is the ease of comprehension. I prefer the first version, but that is just my opinion. (BTW: in your second version, the word "that" is a mistake.)

They are logically equivalent.  The relevant equivalence principle is:
Exportation
$P \to (Q \to R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \to R$
Still, one statement may be preferred (and thus be more ‘proper’) than the other: the first statement effectively points out a certain context for some conditional to hold. As such, if you ever find yourself in a similar context, you can use that conditional. This is probably more useful than stuffing everything into one big conditional … the first statement breaks things up, is more organizational, and is cognitively and conceptually preferred.
